# Why isn't my Windows 7 x64 laptop hibernating properly?

Tags: windows-7, boot, hibernate, standby, acer-travelmate

Usually when I put my Windows 7 x64 Acer TravelMate 5520 laptop into hibernation nowadays, it starts back up in this screen:

[image: Windows Error Recovery]

Text in picture:

> Windows did not shut down successfully. If this was due to the system not responding, or if the system was shut down to protect data, you might be able to recover by choosing one of the Safe Mode configurations from the menu below:
>
> (Use the arrow keys to highlight your choice.)
>
> Safe Mode
>
> Safe Mode with Networking
>
> Safe Mode with Command Prompt
>
> Start Windows Normally
>
> Seconds until the highlighted choice will be selected automatically: 21
>
> Description: Start windows with its regular settings

And then it fails to resume from hibernation. Hibernation used to work perfectly all the time, now it often does this. Sometimes it doesn't do it, but usually it does.

I tried turning on and off hibernate through cmd.exe, but it doesn't seem to consistently fix the problem. I tried restarting when it happens and then it may or may not work after that. Anyone have any idea why this is happening? Searching online didn't find anything.

Hibernation used to work perfectly. I don't want to stop using hibernation.  Standby actually doesn't work either on my computer. For some reason when I start up from standby the sound gets messed up and sometimes these horizontal white lines appear on the screen, and then I have to restart.

Comment: Did you install any new updates recently?

Comment: Is your hard drive getting full?

Comment: It's been doing this for a while, so it's hard to say.  Updates come all the time.  And no my hard drive still has over 150 GB free out of over 400.